# Hiding items in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I want to hide a Button when I press on it.

```
const Button=()=>{
const [hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(false)
function Button(){
 setHideButton(false)
}
return(
<div>

<button onClick={setHideButton}> </button>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: Seems that this is shouldn't be a state of Button component but a state of its parent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially make it `true` to show the button. hide it based on click.

```
const Button=()=>{
const [hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(true)
function handleClick(){
  setHideButton(false)
}
return(
 <div>
   {hideButton && <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>}
 </div>
)}
```

Or just put !(Not) before hideButton -> **`!hideButton`** and make it true on button click.

```
const Button=()=>{
const [hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(false)
function handleClick(){
  setHideButton(true)
}
return(
 <div>
   {!hideButton && <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>}
   <ChildComponent hideButton={hideButton} handleClick={handleClick}/>
 </div>
)}

function ChildComponent ({hideButton, handleClick}) {
  return (
   <>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Child Button</button>
    {!hideButton && <p>
     This is content/paragraph which will be hidden 
     based on based on button click from parent component.
    </p>}
   </> 
  )
}
```

You can change as per your requirement i have passed function and state variable to child component. child button will toggle your content of child component and parent button hide itself once clicked.

Comment: Another question. How would I pass this function to another component for instance when I click on the button it hides the button but also hides something else in other component for example an Icon

Comment: @tekila12 I have changed 2nd example code you can check and change as per your objective. If the answer is helpful for you please vote/accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: there is a problem it double  renders the icon, but nvm I'll figure it out somehow. "Child Component is rendered somewhere else that why double renders it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just conditionally render the button so it doesn't render if `hideButton` is true:

```
return(
  <div>
    {!hideButton && <button onClick={setHideButton}> </button>}
  </div>
  )
```

Comment: Another question. How would I pass this function to another component for instance when I click on the button it hides the button but also hides something else in other component for example an Icon.

Comment: You could do it the exact same way except you would need to pass hideButton or hideIcon as a prop to the child

Answer (score 0):

It is needed to use React hook for doing this.

```
const Button=()=>{
const [hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(false)
function hide(){
 setHideButton(false)
}
return(
<div>

{!hideButton && <button onClick={hide}> </button>}
</div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going wrong here.

This is the way your code should look (one of many ways)

```
const Button = () => {
    const [hideButton, setHideButton] = React.useState(false)
    function handleHideButton() {
        setHideButton(true)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {!hideButton ? <button onClick={handleHideButton}>Hide</button> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

What you were doing wrong:

```
const Button=()=>{
const [hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(false)
// You're creating this function called Button, but should be called something esle like handleHideButton
function Button(){
 // You should be setting this to true when the button is clicked.
 setHideButton(false)
}
return(
<div>
// here you should be calling the handleHideButton function defined above. Calling setHideButton isn't a good option here. 
<button onClick={setHideButton}> </button>
</div>
)
}
```